# Which cloud service is preferred for Hosting a Django Application with RDMS(My SQL) for small scale, Cloud Run or App Engine or Lambda or EC2

Tags: server, cloud, hosting

Hosting Django App with Mysql database for small scale Mobile Application

Detailed comparison of all services with process, load variation, DB support, in terms of cost efficient, no of free services and reliability and serverless setup